# Using Reflex Platform to compile a stack project with local packages

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, frp, nix, reflex

I would like to use the work-on script in reflex-platform to compile a project that has been managed using stack until now as explained [here](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform/blob/develop/HACKING.md).

In the stack.yaml's package list I have a reference to a package located in a local path, something like:

```
packages:
- '.'
- ../<my_package>
```

When I run the script I get a strange nix error saying that an anonymous function has been called without a required argument (with the name of the local package).

> error: anonymous function at
>   /nix/store/sci0xi7jjwl9krpsp051iry1blz0jaw0-cabal2nix-for-unknown-package/default.nix:1:1
>   called without required argument ‘my_package’, at
>   /nix/store/wgg4rzg3hyywfd7b0917qmj4617rza7k-nixpkgs-32833c010ecf868826aaa3b60d322bf697f37134-src/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:69:27

How can I tell nix where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `my_package` using the package overriding mechanism in `haskellPackages`, as described in the [NixPkgs Manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#how-to-build-projects-that-depend-on-each-other)

The `cabal.project` file, as used for this purpose, is roughly equivalent to a set of overrides added to `haskellPackages`. If you're switching entirely to Nix, you can delete the `cabal.project` when you're done, because it will be obsolete. NixPkgs' `haskellPackages` does not have a use for it. It only uses cabal-install to build single packages at a time.